# How to change the background of a page section in Squarespace using CSS?

Tags: css, squarespace

I working with an index of pages in Squarespace. For one page within that index I would like to change the background to be an image. I am trying to change the background of the "About Us" section on [seacureadvisors](https://www.seacureadvisors.com/seacureadvisors). The name of the index is SeacureAdvisors, the name of the page I'm trying to update the background for is Seacure Advisors Button Section.

I have tried the following CSS with no luck:

```
#seacureadvisors #seacure-button-section {
    background-image: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5fce63b9abf5bd69920abec0/t/5fd2163da9eaf43bd85bc941/1607603780287/who+we+are+bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

and

```
div#block-c509aa91e20e639c15e8 {
    background-image: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5fce63b9abf5bd69920abec0/t/5fd2163da9eaf43bd85bc941/1607603780287/who+we+are+bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Neither seems to work. Please advise.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.
[Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/21849374)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the `selector` you are looking for:

```
#seacure-button-section div.index-section-wrapper.page-content{
    background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5fce63b9abf5bd69920abec0/t/5fd2163da9eaf43bd85bc941/1607603780287/who+we+are+bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of the `url()` css function requires a string. To fix it, put the URL into quotes, like so:

```
background-image: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5fce63b9abf5bd69920abec0/t/5fd2163da9eaf43bd8   5bc941/1607603780287/who+we+are+bg.png");
```

Also, your link contains whitespace, which will also break the url.